# Strings into numbers and +, -, * and / - Javascript Equation calculator

Tags: javascript, converters, calculator, equation

I'm working on a 'Equation Calculator' but have a few problems. I can now insert my equation but I want it to be numbers, but not just numbers: I want all the '+' 's, the '-' 's, the '*' 's and the '/' 's to be the right things.

So here is my code until now:

---

```
var ligning = prompt("Insert your equation here:");
var newLigning = ligning.split("=");
var sideOne = parseInt(newLigning[0],10);
var sideTwo = parseInt(newLigning[1],10);
var calculator = function() {

};
alert(sideOne);
alert(sideTwo);
```

---

To be very specific here is an example:

'1 + 2 = 3' should alert 3 and then 3 again (because of the two alerts down in the bottom) - How can I make that?

Comment: this seems like a homework question

Comment: @Patricia and if it is? and he still wants to learn ?

Comment: then it should be tagged accordingly :P

Comment: @Patricia I agree on that. :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "I want all the '+' 's, the '-' 's, the '*' 's and the '/' 's to be the right things."? What are the "right things"?

Comment: @ Code-guru I wanna make the plus, minus, multiplication, and division work the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
var sideOne = parseInt(newLigning[0],10);
```

You might want to have something of the sort :

```
var sideOne = performMath(newLining[0],10);
```

Where :

```
function performMath(equation) {
    //CODE HERE
}
```

`performMath` could be done in a few ways.  You need to split the equation and obtain the numbers and the equations between the 2.  This can be done recursively!

I think this could be a good starting point.

#### Edit

Unraleted to the question, if you start taking the operation priority (PEDMAS) into account this is a slightly harder task.  The approach is the same, `performMath` would need to be slightly more complexe.  In such a case, I would recomend some sort of array structure for the numbers and another for the equations.

#### Edit 2

`Paul S` Also made a good point of sanitising the string before getting started.  You cannot assume someone will enter an equation.  When programming Rich Cook said:

> "Programming today is a race between software engineers striving to
>   build bigger and better idiot- proof programs, and the Universe trying
>   to produce bigger and better idiots. So far, the Universe is winning."

#### Edit 3

This little snippet of code should be somewhat helpful... by all means this might not the most efficient code...

```js
var equation = "1+22-3";
var operators = "+-*\/"

var currentNumber = "";
var numbers = new Array();
var operatorArray = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<equation.length; i++) {
  var currentChar = equation.charAt(i);
  if(operators.indexOf(currentChar) != -1) {
    operatorArray[operatorArray.length] = (currentChar);
    numbers[numbers.length] = (currentNumber);
    currentNumber = "";
  } else {
    currentNumber = currentNumber + currentChar;
    alert(currentNumber);
  }
}
numbers[numbers.length] = currentNumber;
alert("numbers : " + numbers);
alert("operators : " + operatorArray);
```

Now all you have to do is go through the arrays and perform the proper operations.

Comment: Sounds great. I will go to bed now, and will look at the code again tomorrow after school. If I can make it work, will you of course get the 'answarmark'

Comment: So what should I exactly type? Again, I'm still new, and I can't make it work.

Comment: I will not write a program for you, but there are plenty of algorithms out there online to help you out.  [this one](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/214/lectures/lect6/lect6.html) for example is quite good IMO.  Try writing something and update your question with the specific problems you are having.  Then we can update the answers with more specific information.

Comment: Well. My question is how do I make the strings into numbers and the 4 signs (-, +, *, /) so I can calculate with them?

Answer (score 1):

`eval` is really bad and easily abused, but if you know you only take in numbers and specific operators then you could also do some string sanitisation and make it a little safer

```
var ligning = prompt("Insert your equation here:"),
    newLigning = ligning.split("="),
    lhs = newLigning[0],
    rhs = newLigning[1];

function calculate(expr) {
    var s;
    expr = expr.replace(/[^\d*/()+-]/g, ''); // remove everything except permitted
    if (expr !== (s = expr.replace(/^[*/]*|[*/+-]*$/g, ''))) {
        expr = s; // don't allow * or / at the ends
        console.warn('Removing invalid operators');
    };
    return +eval(expr || 0); // + implicit converts to number
};

console.log(lhs = calculate(lhs), rhs = calculate(rhs), lhs === rhs);
```

Comment: I'm still a beginner and that doesn't make any sense to me, so I will try the other one, but otherwise thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert ( eval(newLigning[0]) );
alert ( eval(newLigning[1]) );
```

Comment: now 5000 people will scream " Eval is Evil ! Dont use Eval !"

Comment: Eval is evil! Eval is evil! (Might as well jump on the bandwagon)